# Login Screen keeps asking for password

Tags: virtualbox, login, java, password

I installed Ubuntu 15.10 on VirtualBox today and while trying to install jdk1.8.0_66, I updated `/etc/profile` and `/etc/environment` files for updating JAVA_HOME & PATH variables.

Even after the above changes, the terminal couldn't recognize the changes, so I decided to restart my VM.

Now the problem is, after restarting, The login screen keeps prompting me for a password. Even if I enter the correct password, it somehow restarts the login screen (The VM does not restart, only the login screen) and prompts me for a password. I'm not able to proceed any further from the login screen.

Please let me know how can I fix this problem! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out! I started in recovery mode (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode) and undid all those changes I had made in `/etc/profile` and `/etc/environment`

Now it's booting up perfectly! Unnecessary trouble! :|